# Black edges around the taken screenshot

Tags: android, android-bitmap, android-mediaprojection

I'm following this example :

```
package com.mtsahakis.mediaprojectiondemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.OrientationEventListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;


public class ScreenCaptureImageActivity extends Activity {

    private static final String TAG = ScreenCaptureImageActivity.class.getName();
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static String STORE_DIRECTORY;
    private static int IMAGES_PRODUCED;
    private static final String SCREENCAP_NAME = "screencap";
    private static final int VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAGS = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
    private static MediaProjection sMediaProjection;

    private MediaProjectionManager mProjectionManager;
    private ImageReader mImageReader;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private Display mDisplay;
    private VirtualDisplay mVirtualDisplay;
    private int mDensity;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mHeight;
    private int mRotation;
    private OrientationChangeCallback mOrientationChangeCallback;

    private class ImageAvailableListener implements ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image image = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            try {
                image = mImageReader.acquireLatestImage();
                if (image != null) {
                    Image.Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                    ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                    int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride();
                    int rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride();
                    int rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * mWidth;

                    // create bitmap
                    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

                    // write bitmap to a file
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(STORE_DIRECTORY + "/myscreen_" + IMAGES_PRODUCED + ".png");
                    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);

                    IMAGES_PRODUCED++;
                    Log.e(TAG, "captured image: " + IMAGES_PRODUCED);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (fos!=null) {
                    try {
                        fos.close();
                    } catch (IOException ioe) {
                        ioe.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                if (bitmap!=null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }

                if (image!=null) {
                    image.close();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class OrientationChangeCallback extends OrientationEventListener {
        public OrientationChangeCallback(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            synchronized (this) {
                final int rotation = mDisplay.getRotation();
                if (rotation != mRotation) {
                    mRotation = rotation;
                    try {
                        // clean up
                        if(mVirtualDisplay != null) mVirtualDisplay.release();
                        if(mImageReader != null) mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);

                        // re-create virtual display depending on device width / height
                        createVirtualDisplay();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class MediaProjectionStopCallback extends MediaProjection.Callback {
        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            Log.e("ScreenCapture", "stopping projection.");
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(mVirtualDisplay != null) mVirtualDisplay.release();
                    if(mImageReader != null) mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);
                    if(mOrientationChangeCallback != null) mOrientationChangeCallback.disable();
                    sMediaProjection.unregisterCallback(MediaProjectionStopCallback.this);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    /****************************************** Activity Lifecycle methods ************************/
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // call for the projection manager
        mProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);

        // start projection
        Button startButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startProjection();
            }
        });

        // stop projection
        Button stopButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                stopProjection();
            }
        });

        // start capture handling thread
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                mHandler = new Handler();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            sMediaProjection = mProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data);

            if (sMediaProjection != null) {
                File externalFilesDir = getExternalFilesDir(null);
                if (externalFilesDir != null) {
                    STORE_DIRECTORY = externalFilesDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/screenshots/";
                    File storeDirectory = new File(STORE_DIRECTORY);
                    if (!storeDirectory.exists()) {
                        boolean success = storeDirectory.mkdirs();
                        if (!success) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory.");
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "failed to create file storage directory, getExternalFilesDir is null.");
                    return;
                }

                // display metrics
                DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
                mDensity = metrics.densityDpi;
                mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();

                // create virtual display depending on device width / height
                createVirtualDisplay();

                // register orientation change callback
                mOrientationChangeCallback = new OrientationChangeCallback(this);
                if (mOrientationChangeCallback.canDetectOrientation()) {
                    mOrientationChangeCallback.enable();
                }

                // register media projection stop callback
                sMediaProjection.registerCallback(new MediaProjectionStopCallback(), mHandler);
            }
        }
    }

    /****************************************** UI Widget Callbacks *******************************/
    private void startProjection() {
        startActivityForResult(mProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void stopProjection() {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (sMediaProjection != null) {
                    sMediaProjection.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /****************************************** Factoring Virtual Display creation ****************/
    private void createVirtualDisplay() {
        // get width and height
        Point size = new Point();
        mDisplay.getSize(size);
        mWidth = size.x;
        mHeight = size.y;

        // start capture reader
        mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(mWidth, mHeight, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 2);
        mVirtualDisplay = sMediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(SCREENCAP_NAME, mWidth, mHeight, mDensity, VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAGS, mImageReader.getSurface(), null, mHandler);
        mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new ImageAvailableListener(), mHandler);
    }
}
```

to take a screenshot on `Android ver >=21`.

The problem with that example is that once I take the screenshot , there are black edges on the `top` , `right` & `bottom` of the `Image`.

I can't see where is the problem since the given `Width` and `Height` to both the `VirtualDisplay` and the `Bitmap` are correct, what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 7):

Problem is probably the size of the virtual display.

```
mDisplay.getSize(size);
```

may return something different than the real size of the device if your device have a virtual navigation bar (usually swipe from bottom of the screen to display it).

```
mDisplay.getRealSize(size);
```

will probably fix your problem with black edges.

Comment: Nexus 5X still has black edge because both getSize() and getRealSize() return 1080 but it shouldn't. Height no such problem though.

Answer (score 1):

```
Rect rect = image.getCropRect();
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, rect.left, rect.top, rect.width(), rect.height());
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: It's self explain. The question is 'where is the problem since the given Width and Height are correct', and this code snippet is telling where the real width/height is.