# How to properly take a screenshot, globally?

Tags: android, screenshot, android-mediaprojection

### Background

Since Android API 21, it's possible for apps to take screenshots globally and record the screen.

### The problem

I've made a sample code out of all I've found on the Internet, but it has a few issues:

1. It's quite slow. Maybe it's possible to avoid it, at least for multiple screenshots, by avoiding the notification of it being removed till really not needed.
2. It has black margins on left and right, meaning something might be wrong with the calculations :

[image]

### What I've tried

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int REQUEST_ID = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.checkIfPossibleToRecordButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                ScreenshotManager.INSTANCE.requestScreenshotPermission(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_ID);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.takeScreenshotButton).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                ScreenshotManager.INSTANCE.takeScreenshot(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ID)
            ScreenshotManager.INSTANCE.onActivityResult(resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

**layout/activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkIfPossibleToRecordButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="request if possible"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/takeScreenshotButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="take screenshot"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**ScreenshotManager**

```
public class ScreenshotManager {
    private static final String SCREENCAP_NAME = "screencap";
    private static final int VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAGS = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
    public static final ScreenshotManager INSTANCE = new ScreenshotManager();
    private Intent mIntent;

    private ScreenshotManager() {
    }

    public void requestScreenshotPermission(@NonNull Activity activity, int requestId) {
        MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        activity.startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), requestId);
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null)
            mIntent = data;
        else mIntent = null;
    }

    @UiThread
    public boolean takeScreenshot(@NonNull Context context) {
        if (mIntent == null)
            return false;
        final MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        final MediaProjection mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(Activity.RESULT_OK, mIntent);
        if (mediaProjection == null)
            return false;
        final int density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        final Display display = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        final Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        final int width = size.x, height = size.y;

        // start capture reader
        final ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 1);
        final VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay = mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(SCREENCAP_NAME, width, height, density, VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAGS, imageReader.getSurface(), null, null);
        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {
                Log.d("AppLog", "onImageAvailable");
                mediaProjection.stop();
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Bitmap doInBackground(final Void... params) {
                        Image image = null;
                        Bitmap bitmap = null;
                        try {
                            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                            if (image != null) {
                                Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                                ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                                int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride(), rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride(), rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;
                                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width + rowPadding / pixelStride, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
                                bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);
                                return bitmap;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            if (bitmap != null)
                                bitmap.recycle();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (image != null)
                            image.close();
                        reader.close();
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap bitmap) {
                        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                        Log.d("AppLog", "Got bitmap?" + (bitmap != null));
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        }, null);
        mediaProjection.registerCallback(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                if (virtualDisplay != null)
                    virtualDisplay.release();
                imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);
                mediaProjection.unregisterCallback(this);
            }
        }, null);
        return true;
    }
}
```

### The questions

Well it's about the problems:

1. Why is it so slow? Is there a way to improve it?
2. How can I avoid, between taking screenshots, the removal of the notification of them? When can I remove the notification? Does the notification mean it constantly takes screenshots?
3. Why does the output bitmap (currently I don't do anything with it, because it's still POC) have black margins in it? What's wrong with the code in this matter?

NOTE: I don't want to take a screenshot only of the current app. I want to know how to use it globally, for all apps, which is possible officially only by using this API, as far as I know.

---

EDIT: I've noticed that on CommonsWare website ([**here**](https://commonsware.com/Android/previews/screenshots-and-screen-recordings)), it is said that the output bitmap is larger for some reason, but as opposed to what I've noticed (black margin in beginning AND end), it says it's supposed to be in the end:

> For inexplicable reasons, it will be a bit larger, with excess unused
>   pixels on each row on the end.

I've tried what was offered there, but it crashes with the exception "java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels" .

Comment: I didn't look at this in detail, but you might be missing the real screen size (DisplayMetrics.getRealMetrics) and only grabbing the window size.
Here's a working example that may help: https://github.com/mattprecious/telescope/blob/ce5e2710fb16ee214026fc25b091eb946fdbbb3c/telescope/src/main/java/com/mattprecious/telescope/TelescopeLayout.java

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your notifications concern. A projection icon is displayed in the status bar when Media Projection API is in use. A dialog is also presented to the user to NOTIFY them that their screen will be captured by the app that is starting the screen capture intent object obtained from the media projection service.

Comment: @AnkitBatra Yes, I want the "projection icon" to stay, because I think it will avoid re-initializing the whole process. Is it possible to avoid the re-initializing between screen-captures? Currently it shows, hides, shows, hides...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Why does the output bitmap (currently I don't do anything with it, because it's still POC) have black margins in it? What's wrong with the code in this matter?*

You have black margins around your screenshot because you are not using realSize of the window you're in. To solve this:

1. Get the real size of the window:

```
    final Point windowSize = new Point();
    WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(windowSize);
```

2. Use that to create your image reader:

```
    imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(windowSize.x, windowSize.y, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, MAX_IMAGES);
```

3. This third step may not be required but I have seen otherwise in my app's production code (which runs on a variety of android devices out there). When you acquire an image for ImageReader and create a bitmap out of it. Crop that bitmap using the window size using below code.

```
    // fix the extra width from Image
    Bitmap croppedBitmap;
    try {
        croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, windowSize.x, windowSize.y);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        Timber.d(e, "Out of memory when cropping bitmap of screen size");
        croppedBitmap = bitmap;
    }
    if (croppedBitmap != bitmap) {
        bitmap.recycle();
    }
```

*I don't want to take a screenshot only of the current app. I want to know how to use it globally, for all apps, which is possible officially only by using this API, as far as I know.*

To capture screen/take screenshot you need an object of MediaProjection. To create such object, you need pair of resultCode (int) and Intent. You already know how these objects are acquired and cache those in your ScreenshotManager class.

Coming back to taking screenshots of any app, you need to follow the same procedure of getting these variables resultCode and Intent but instead of caching it locally in your class variables, start a background service and pass these variables to the same like any other normal parameters. Take a look at how Telecine does it [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Telecine/blob/master/telecine/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/telecine/CaptureHelper.java). When this background service is started it can provide a trigger (a notification button) to the user which when clicked, will perform the same operations of capturing screen/taking screenshot as you are doing in your ScreenshotManager class.

*Why is it so slow? Is there a way to improve it?*

How much slow is it to your expectations? My use case for Media projection API is to take a screenshot and present it to the user for editing. For me the speed is decent enough. One thing I feel worth mentioning is that the ImageReader class can accept a Handler to a thread in setOnImageAvailableListener. If you provide a handler there, onImageAvailable callback will be triggered on the handler thread instead of the one that created the ImageReader. This will help you in NOT creating a AsyncTask (and starting it) when an image is available instead the callback itself will happen on a background thread. This is how I create my ImageReader:

```
    private void createImageReader() {
            startBackgroundThread();
            imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(windowSize.x, windowSize.y, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, MAX_IMAGES);
            ImageHandler imageHandler = new ImageHandler(context, domainModel, windowSize, this, notificationManager, analytics);
            imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageHandler, backgroundHandler);
        }

    private void startBackgroundThread() {
            backgroundThread = new HandlerThread(NAME_VIRTUAL_DISPLAY);
            backgroundThread.start();
            backgroundHandler = new Handler(backgroundThread.getLooper());
        }
```

Comment: The margin issue is solved, by both using a better size, and then cropping. About the speed, using a handler didn't help. However, can you please show how to let the notification stay between screen captures? For example, I want to trigger the screen capture at certain time, and later when something else triggers it. I think this will at least improve speed of capturing after the first capture, because it won't need to re-initialize every time.

Comment: The solution of "newInstance" doesn't allow to have too many images (example 1000), and even with a few images (10), the notification still get removed .

Comment: It seems it is actually fast. Just that for the user, the indication is quite slow and doesn't disappear right away. If you know how to avoid this weird UX (by letting the indication stay till I finish with all screenshots), please let me know. For now, this is the correct answer and I will mark it.

Comment: If you want the projection icon to stay then you will have to forbid calling mediaProjection.stop() in your code which stops the projection and eventually hides the icon. However, I imagine there could be some issues (like slowness, battery drainage etc) if you keep media projection running in the background. I don't think there is a way to control the projection icon displayed in the status bar. But I have not investigated enough in this direction. Also, I feel you can create better UX experience by explaining/hinting to the user about the icon so that you don't lose out too much on UX.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate how to do it well? I think I'm doing something wrong trying to do it.

Comment: Please paste your code or share the link so the community can take a look.

Comment: @androiddeveloper, you already knew that this your class not is working on Android **7.0** (comes a black image)? could fix it please? i think this class very interest, mainly because of `AsyncTask`.

Comment: @MarcioGomes It should work stating from API 21 , which is Android 5.0. Please try on emulator.

Comment: @androiddeveloper, then you made this class only to work on versions 5.0 and 5.1? i tested on my **Moto G5s Plus** v.7.1.1 and not worked, comes a black screen.

Comment: @androiddeveloper, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756298/black-edges-around-the-taken-screenshot) is a code that i tested and works on 7.0 and 7.1.1, but not know if also works on 5.1 or 6.0. Even so, this code not meets my need because uses make a infinite loop ( for example, fails on server side when we want send these screenshots via socket because of this infinite loop). Try fix your code (to works in recent versions of android) based in this code that i linked and update on Github ;-).

Comment: @MarcioGomes Sadly I have one device, and it's on 8.1, and emulators don't work on my pc because I have AMD CPU. Can't help you. I remember I did succeed making it work on other versions, but don't remember which.