# how to capture a screenshot?

Tags: android, screenshot

I know that there are a lot of questions about capturing screenshots, and I have checked most of them. They have the same answer (with small code variations).

I have following method for screenshot capturing:

```
@NonNull
public static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Window window) throws IOException {
    final View rootView = window.getDecorView().getRootView();
    final boolean drawingCacheEnabled = rootView.isDrawingCacheEnabled();
    rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

    try {
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(rootView.getDrawingCache());
    } finally {
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(drawingCacheEnabled);
    }
}
```

And you can use it like these: `takeScreenShot(getActivity().getWindow())`

However these approach has several limitations:

1. If you have some dialogs on the screen they will not be captured on 
   screenshot.
2. Will it work with hardware accelerated views? According
   to documentation:

   > When hardware acceleration is turned on, enabling the
   >   drawing cache has no effect on rendering because the system uses a
   >   different mechanism for acceleration which ignores the flag
3. Screenshot contains black boxes
   instead of GLviews. (e.g. when you app has maps.). It seems to be as a result of 2nd point.

So my question is, is there any solution without rooting that can solve at least some of my issues?

Comment: At lease I would like to capture dialogs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the following GitHub repo (not mine!):  https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB/ScreenshotSample

Also, the following will be useful reading:
[How to properly take a screenshot, globally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43705756/how-to-properly-take-a-screenshot-globally)