# How make a TServerSocket multithread?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, delphi

I'm testing how get periodical screenshots of my Android smartphone and already  that this server is receiving a big flux of screenshots form my device, happens that these images not appear in `TImage`, i think that is because `TServerSocket` (part where receives images) not is in a thread. And yes, i'm sending these screenshots correctly:

**Java (Android):**

```
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mWidth + rowPadding / pixelStride, mHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
    byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    dos.writeInt(array.length);
    dos.write(array, 0, array.length);

    dos.flush();
```

And here is my Delphi code where must receive the periodical screenshots:

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;

   stSize: integer;   
   Stream: TMemoryStream; 
   Receiving: boolean; 
   png: TPngImage; 

   FSize: Integer;
   writing: Boolean;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
Item: TListItem;  
begin
    Item := ListView1.Items.Add;   
    Item.Caption := IntTostr(socket.Handle); 
    Item.SubItems.Add(Socket.RemoteAddress); 
    Item.SubItems.Add(socket.RemoteHost);  
    Item.Data := Socket.Data; 
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
Item: TListItem;
begin  
    Item:= ListView1.FindCaption(0, inttostr(socket.Handle), false, true, false);
    if item <> nil then
    Item.Delete;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
    showmessage('socket erro'); 
    ErrorCode := 0;  
end;

procedure TForm1.Activate1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ServerSocket1.Active := true;  
end;

procedure TForm1.Deactive1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ServerSocket1.Active := false;  
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Stream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
    writing:= False;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendMyReqst1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if ListView1.Selected = nil then exit;    
    ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[ListView1.ItemIndex].SendText('screencapture' + #13#10); 
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  BytesReceived: Longint;
  CopyBuffer: Pointer;
  ChunkSize: Integer;
  TempSize: Integer;
const
  MaxChunkSize: Longint = 8192;
begin

  If FSize=0 then
  begin
    begin
      Socket.ReceiveBuf(TempSize,SizeOf(TempSize));
      TempSize := ntohl(TempSize);
      Stream.SetSize(TempSize);
      FSize:= TempSize
    End;
  End;

  If (FSize>0) and not(writing) then
  begin
    GetMem(CopyBuffer, MaxChunkSize);
    writing:= True;
    While Socket.ReceiveLength>0 do
    Begin
      ChunkSize:= Socket.ReceiveLength;
      If ChunkSize > MaxChunkSize then ChunkSize:= MaxChunkSize;
      BytesReceived:= Socket.ReceiveBuf(CopyBuffer^,ChunkSize);
      Stream.Write(CopyBuffer^, BytesReceived);
      Dec(FSize,BytesReceived);
    End;
  end;

  If FSize=0 then begin

  Stream.Position := 0;
  png:=TPngImage.Create;
  png.LoadFromStream(Stream);
  img1.Picture.Assign(png);
  img1.Refresh;
  Stream.SetSize(0);
  png.Free;
  FSize:= 0;
end;

FreeMem(CopyBuffer, MaxChunkSize);
Writing:= False;
end;

end.
```

[image]

This Delphi code above works fine, but to receive only 1 screenshot, not a big flux.

**UPDATE:**

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756298/black-edges-around-the-taken-screenshot) is my code base for obtain periodical screenshots on Android.

*PS*: See that he use a infinite loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: "Bitmap Image is not valid" on received from Socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20292986/error-message-bitmap-image-is-not-valid-on-received-from-socket)

Comment: @RemyLebeau, `This code does not need to be multi-threaded to work correctly. It needs to be fixed` even that is executing a infinite loop of screenshots and sending on client side will work?

Comment: @RemyLebeau, see my edition above.

Comment: @JeffersonFarias Like I said, the reading code is all wrong and needs to be rewritten. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Delphi code you have shown DOES NOT correctly account for the streaming nature of TCP, or for multiple clients:

- it is NOT reading `FSize` correctly. More than 1 read may be needed to get all 4 bytes.
- it DOES NOT use `FSize` to limit the number of bytes read for the PNG stream. You need to read exactly how many bytes `FSize` specifies, no more, no less. It is reading as long as the client is still sending bytes, even if they belong to subsequent messages. It needs to stop reading when it reaches the end of the stream, and then reset for the next message.
- it DOES NOT handle the possibility of multiple clients sending screenshots at the same time. It is sharing variables with multiple clients, thus allowing them to corrupt each other's messages.

In short, the code is COMPLETELY broken, regardless of multi-threading. Which, BTW, is not a factor if you use the server in non-blocking mode (which the code likely is, as that is the server's default mode, and the code is not using any of the server's thread-related events).

The code does not need to be multi-threaded to work correctly. It needs to be rewritten to operate correctly.

Try something more like this:

```
type
  TInt32Bytes = record
    case Integer of
      0: (Bytes: array[0..SizeOf(Int32)-1] of Byte);
      1: (Value: Int32);
  end;

  TSocketState = (ReadingSize, ReadingStream);

  TSocketData = class
  public
    Stream: TMemoryStream;
    Png: TPngImage;
    State: TSocketState;
    Size: TInt32Bytes;
    Offset: Integer;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TSocketData.Create;
begin
  Stream := TMemoryStream.Create;
  Png := TPngImage.Create;
end;

destructor TSocketData.Destroy;
begin
  Stream.Free;
  Png.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientConnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Socket.Data := TSocketData.Create;
  Item := ListView1.Items.Add;
  Item.Data := Socket;
  Item.Caption := IntToStr(Socket.Handle);
  Item.SubItems.Add(Socket.RemoteAddress);
  Item.SubItems.Add(Socket.RemoteHost);
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientDisconnect(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  Item := ListView1.FindData(0, Socket, true, false);
  if Item <> nil then Item.Delete;
  TSocketData(Socket.Data).Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientError(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket; ErrorEvent: TErrorEvent; var ErrorCode: Integer);
begin
  ErrorCode := 0;
  Socket.Close;
end;

procedure TForm1.Activate1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ServerSocket1.Active := true;
end;

procedure TForm1.Deactive1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ServerSocket1.Active := false;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendMyReqst1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Index := ListView1.ItemIndex;
  if Index = -1 then Exit;
  ServerSocket1.Socket.Connections[Index].SendText('screencapture' + #13#10);
end;

procedure TForm1.ServerSocket1ClientRead(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  BytesReceived: Integer;
  BufferPtr: PByte;
  SD: TSocketData;
  Item: TListItem;
begin
  SD := TSocketData(Socket.Data);

  if SD.State = ReadingSize then
  begin
    while SD.Offset < SizeOf(Int32) do
    begin
      BytesReceived := Socket.ReceiveBuf(SD.Size.Bytes[SD.Offset], SizeOf(Int32) - SD.Offset);
      if BytesReceived <= 0 then Exit;
      Inc(SD.Offset, BytesReceived);
    end;
    SD.Size.Value := ntohl(SD.Size.Value);
    SD.State := ReadingStream;
    SD.Offset := 0;
    SD.Stream.Size := SD.Size.Value;
  end;

  if SD.State = ReadingStream then
  begin
    if SD.Offset < SD.Size.Value then
    begin
      BufferPtr := PByte(SD.Stream.Memory);
      Inc(BufferPtr, SD.Offset);
      repeat
        BytesReceive := Socket.ReceiveBuf(BufferPtr^, SD.Size.Value - SD.Offset);
        if BytesReceived <= 0 then Exit;
        Inc(BufferPtr, BytesReceived);
        Inc(SD.Offset, BytesReceived);
      until SD.Offset = SD.Size.Value;
    end;
    try
      SD.Stream.Position := 0;
      SD.Png.LoadFromStream(SD.Stream);
    except
      SD.Png.Assign(nil);
    end;
    Item := ListView1.Selected;
    if (Item <> nil) and (Item.Data = Socket) then
      img1.Picture.Assign(SD.Png);
    SD.State := ReadingSize;
    SD.Offset := 0;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ListView1SelectItem(Sender: TObject; Item: TListItem; Selected: Boolean);
begin
  if (Item <> nil) and Selected then
    img1.Picture.Assign(TSocketData(TCustomWinSocket(Item.Data).Data).Png);
end;
```

Comment: your code receives the screenshot but after some seconds occur this error: [Error](https://image.prntscr.com/image/2A8i50HFQdyfXfuFunHhqA.png) and [Line](https://image.prntscr.com/image/ooqMXa-rSI_dF2dVmPhkgg.png)

Comment: This can be because big flux of data of infinite loop of Android code?

Comment: @JeffersonFarias my bad, I forgot to increment `BufferPtr` while reading the PNG stream. I tweaked the code in my answer.

Comment: @JeffersonFarias you keep saying there is an infinite loop in the Android code, but I see none.

Comment: the linked question show a code that take screenshot periodically (pratically in a infinite loop), i tested!. And because it, any Delphi code not works, not support this type of thing (receiving multiples screenshot without none control about this, we saying of 2 or more screeshots/second). If you test the this android code will see

Comment: @JeffersonFarias I have no intention of testing it. That is your job. But even if Android were sending screenshots in an infinite loop, the Delphi code I gave you should handle it fine, as it supports receiving multiple messages per connection. Just make sure the Android code is actually sending what Delphi is expecting (4-byte size in network byte order, followed by PNG data of the specified size), consistently and cohesively. If something is not working the way you expect, then it is your job to debug it and find out why.