# Why receive the length of data in a loop?

Tags: loops, sockets, delphi, size, delphi-10.4-sydney

I already saw code to receive data through sockets which contains two loops:

1. Receive length of data
2. Receive data itself

...for example (see these answers):

- [Socket is not working as it should help!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5575287/22401964)
- [Error to receive file on socket inside a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48031088/22401964)

...but the **length** of the data is not so big as the data itself. Then what's the goal of this "extra loop" to receive only a string like `'1048'`? I belive that could be received in one single loop together with the data itself.

Comment: I'm not fully sure what you means since you don't show any code what you envision as the better solution. But I have the feeling that you assume that a single TCP send is matched by exactly one TCP receive with exactly the same buffer received as send - i.e. that TCP has some kind of message semantics built in. This assumption is wrong

Comment: The "size" itself is data, too, and you cannot expect to get 4 bytes (32 bit integer) at once - it could also come in as 2 bytes, 1 byte and seconds later the 4th byte. Those are [network packets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_packet) and you already experienced this by f.e. downloads which hang or break in the middle of the transfer. Also: it's time to take the [tour]. The proper English word is [leng**th**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/length).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is a byte stream, it has no concept of messages.  So, there are only 3 ways for the receiver to know when a full message has been received:

- all of the messages are a fixed-length.  The receiver simply reads that many bytes each time.
- the sender sends a message's length before sending the message itself.  The receiver reads the length first, then reads however many bytes the length says.
- the sender sends a unique terminator after each message.  The receiver reads until that terminator is received.

There is no 1:1 relationship between a send and a read on a TCP socket. Any individual read operation can return fewer bytes than requested, so you need a loop to make sure you have received all of the bytes that you are expecting.

So, in the 2nd case, one loop is needed for reading the bytes of the message length, and then another loop for reading the bytes of the message.