# black screenshot on android 7.1.1

Tags: android, android-mediaprojection

I use the following code to capture screen of my device (Android 5.1.1). But when tested this same code on smartphone of my friend (Android 7.1.1), all image is black.

There are some modification where i can make that is able to solve it?

Or is a case that not have solution?

Here is code:

===========================================================================

*ScreenShot:*

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.hardware.display.DisplayManager;
import android.hardware.display.VirtualDisplay;
import android.media.Image;
import android.media.Image.Plane;
import android.media.ImageReader;
import android.media.ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjection.Callback;
import android.media.projection.MediaProjectionManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.UiThread;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import static android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory;

public class ScreenShotManager {

    private static final String SCREENCAP_NAME = "screencap";
    private static final int VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAGS = DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_OWN_CONTENT_ONLY | DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_PUBLIC;
    public static final ScreenShotManager INSTANCE = new ScreenShotManager();
    private Intent mIntent;

    private ScreenShotManager() {
    }

    public void requestScreenshotPermission(@NonNull Activity activity, int requestId) {
        MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        activity.startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent(), requestId);
    }


    public void onActivityResult(int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null)
            mIntent = data;
        else mIntent = null;
    }

    @UiThread
    public boolean takeScreenshot(@NonNull Context context) {
        if (mIntent == null)
            return false;
        final MediaProjectionManager mediaProjectionManager = (MediaProjectionManager) context.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE);
        final MediaProjection mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(Activity.RESULT_OK, mIntent);
        if (mediaProjection == null)
            return false;
        final int density = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().densityDpi;
        final Point windowSize = new Point();
        WindowManager windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        windowManager.getDefaultDisplay().getRealSize(windowSize);
        final int width = windowSize.x, height = windowSize.y;
        final Context applicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();

        // start capture reader
        final ImageReader imageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(width, height, PixelFormat.RGBA_8888, 1);
        final VirtualDisplay virtualDisplay = mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(SCREENCAP_NAME, width, height, density, VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAGS, imageReader.getSurface(), null, null);

        imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(new OnImageAvailableListener() {
            @Override
            public void onImageAvailable(final ImageReader reader) {
                Log.d("AppLog", "onImageAvailable");
                mediaProjection.stop();
                new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Bitmap doInBackground(final Void... params) {
                        Image image = null;
                        Bitmap bitmap = null;
                        try {
                            image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
                            if (image != null) {
                                Plane[] planes = image.getPlanes();
                                ByteBuffer buffer = planes[0].getBuffer();
                                int pixelStride = planes[0].getPixelStride(), rowStride = planes[0].getRowStride(), rowPadding = rowStride - pixelStride * width;
                                bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width + rowPadding / pixelStride, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
                                bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buffer);

                                FileOutputStream out = null;
                                out = new FileOutputStream(getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "test.jpeg");
                                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);


                                // fix the extra width from Image
                                Bitmap croppedBitmap;
                                croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, windowSize.x, windowSize.y);
                                if (croppedBitmap != bitmap)
                                    bitmap.recycle();
                                return croppedBitmap;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            if (bitmap != null)
                                bitmap.recycle();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        if (image != null)
                            image.close();
                        reader.close();
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(final Bitmap bitmap) {
                        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                        Log.d("AppLog", "Got bitmap?" + (bitmap != null));
                        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Got bitmap?" + (bitmap != null), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        }, null);

        mediaProjection.registerCallback(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onStop() {
                super.onStop();
                if (virtualDisplay != null)
                    virtualDisplay.release();
                imageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(null, null);
                mediaProjection.unregisterCallback(this);
            }
        }, null);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
class PermissionUtils {
    public static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 2000;

    public static void requestExternal(Activity context) {
        if (!checkExternal(context)) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(context, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkExternal(Context context) {
        return !(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
    }

}

private final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_PERM = 1234;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        PermissionUtils.requestExternal(this);
        ScreenShotManager.INSTANCE.requestScreenshotPermission(MainActivity.this, REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_PERM);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_PERM) {
            ScreenShotManager.INSTANCE.onActivityResult(resultCode, data);
            ScreenShotManager.INSTANCE.takeScreenshot(MainActivity.this);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have read over your issue and everything seems correct to me. The only thing you need to be mindful of when you are migrating between versions is that the code for every version may be a little different, so you may need to see if the code that version 5.1.1 uses is the same as the code version 7.1.1 uses. If this doesn't work, please reply and i shall find another solution and tell it to you. Good luck!

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37756298/black-edges-around-the-taken-screenshot) is a code that i tested and works on 7.1.1, but not know if also works on 5.1 or 6.0. Even so, this code not meets my need because uses `Looper` ( for example, falha on server side when we want send these screenshots via socket because of this infinite loop that `Looper` makes).